# Scala REPL on windows doesn't accept certain characters

Tags: scala, read-eval-print-loop

I installed Scala 2.11.4 on Windows 8 Pro German (with German keyboard).

When I start the REPL by typing "scala", to get '[' I need to type it 2 times and I can't get ']' and '\' at all - simply nothing happens when I hit "alt gr + 9" or "alt gr + ß" (']' and '\' respectively on the German keyboard).

Any ideas what's wrong?

By the way I have the same problem in the Clojure REPL.

Comment: It's most likely a problem with your terminal, not with scala. Consider rephrasing your question and/or posting it at a different forum, such as superuser.com.

Comment: @aioobe: Don't think so. In other shells (like python, sbcl, etc.) all works correctly. I think it's a problem with the scala/clojure reader which can probably be configured.

Comment: I think you are experiencing this bug: https://github.com/jline/jline2/issues/156

Comment: @Gábor: exactly that seems to be my problem.

Comment: According to https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-8759, it seems to be a bug in jline-2.12.jar.

I replaced jline-2.12.jar in scala\bin with jline-2.11.jar and now it works fine.

Very strange that this is not fixed in the Scala download. With this bug the REPL is just not usable in "alt gr" bound keyboards.

A very frustrating experience if you want to start experimenting with the language.

Comment: @Gábor: Thanks, your hint saved my day. Have been trying to find that problem for several weeks.

Comment: I am glad it worked for you. :) (I think the reasoning behind using the latest version might something that the older version also had problems. Hopefully the next jline release will fix this bug.)

Comment: The new Scala versions (2.10.5 and 2.11.6) are supposed to fix this issue: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/scala-announce/xBNTkk_0K5g/xYAR1T6j5skJ